# flock doesn't block

Tags: c++, c, linux, file, concurrency

I want to synchronize access to files. I am using Linux and g++.

I would like to lock the file by using the function `flock()`.
I developed 2 tests applications writing and reading to/from the same file. 
They both call `flock()` with `LOCK_SH`.

The writer starts first, writes and then sleeps. The second app starts later.
I was expecting to see the reader app blocking when it calls `flock()` since the writer process didn't release  the lock.

Is this the right expectation or do they block ONLY when `read()` and `write()` are called concurrently i.e. at the same exact time?
What have I misunderstood?

```
    PROG A                PROG B
    -open file
    -flock                -open file
    -write                -sleep 5     
    -sleep 1000           -flock    ** expected to block ?? **
    -close                -read data
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`flock` would only block if at least one process uses it with `LOCK_EX`:

- If some process holds exclusive lock then any process trying get exclusive/shared lock will be blocked.
- If some process holds shared lock then process trying to get exclusive lock will be blocked.

In general you should use shared locks for read and exclusive for write or read/write.

Answer (score 2):

`LOCK_SH` is a shared lock. This means there's no problem in several processes holding such a lock simultaneously. This kind of lock is used by readers.